# Updating Database, PUT 405 Method not allowed error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to update my database via a PUT method:

```
      const eventid = arg.event.id;
      const eventData = {
        start: arg.event.start.toISOString(),
        end: arg.event.end.toISOString(),
      };
      const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;
      console.log(csrfToken);
      fetch(`/api/event/update/${eventid}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
        },
        body: encodeFormData(eventData),
      })
```

The specific error is `PUT HTTP://localhost:8000/api/event/update/105 405 (Method not allowed).
I have tried other methods but they all return similar errors. Additionally here is my Controller code:

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($request->id);
        $booking->start_date = $request->start;
        $booking->end_date = $request->end;
        $booking->save();

        return response()->json($booking);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/event/update/{eventid}', [CalendarController::class, 'update']);
```

Is this an issue with using 'post' in my route?

Comment: Hi, If you are using `PUT` method, you need to use `Route::put('/event/update/{eventid}', [CalendarController::class, 'update']);`, You could also make your method `POST`

Comment: Thanks, i've corrected it now but it is providing a 404 error in place instead.

Comment: I see you're calling to `/api/event/update/${eventid}` and the route is `/event/update/{eventid}` Is the route nested in a group for `api` prefix(or api.php file)?

Comment: Yes, it is located within my api.php file which is why I'm confused as to why it can't locate it properly.

Comment: can you type `php artisan route:list` in cli to see your actual registered routes?

Comment: Sure, from what I see it seems like it is getting a correct route. https://imgur.com/oXnYEs5

Comment: Ahh I think I know what's up: `$booking = Booking::findOrFail($request->id);` >> This returns 404 if the `id` does not exist. Can you verify you are sending an existing id?

Comment: I see you are fetching the id with name `eventid` if you add an argument to your controller's function, it should work : `public function update(Request $request, $eventid)`. Just make sure you use `$booking = Booking::findOrFail($eventid);`

Comment: Certainly, I console.logged my id and it does show the correct one which corresponds to the one in my database.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is that you are not performing the right type of request, you might need to verify it in your browser

Comment: Looking in my browser it doesn't seem to provide much information on the request https://imgur.com/qbZ9oiO. Just to be sure, my database includes the table 'bookings' where I believe the s is added on. All my other functions work as well by referencing '$booking'

Comment: I think your `$request->id` is empty because you are sending it named `eventid`. Can you verify by doing `dd($request->id);` as first thing in the `update` function?

Comment: Strange, it does not seem to output anything in the browser console at all. https://imgur.com/ImoWlEW

Comment: If no 404, try looking back at my comment with resolution `$booking = Booking::findOrFail($eventid);`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that `dd($request->id);` doesn't output anything at all. The 404 error is still present. I have also tried your resolution, no change though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know that your variables return what you expect them to return is to test as you code.

From my experience, I find that when I dd() variables at every point I declare and instantiate a variable, especially those passed to a function, it saves me a lot of headache.

Change your update method needs to change from:

```
  public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($request->id);
        $booking->start_date = $request->start;
        $booking->end_date = $request->end;
        $booking->save();

        return response()->json($booking);
    }
```

To:

```
   public function update(Request $request, $event_id)
    {
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($event_id);
        $booking->start_date = $request->start;
        $booking->end_date = $request->end;
        $booking->save();

        return response()->json($booking);
    }
```